# Complex (non string) return type for Jersey REST method

Tags: rest, jersey

I'm having trouble setting something up that I'm pretty sure /should/ be easy, so I thought I'd throw it to the crowd. I can't seem to find what I'm looking for elsewhere on the web or on SE.

I am simplifying my project of course, but basically I have a JAX-WS annontated Jersey resource class that looks something like this:

```
@Path("myresource")
public class MyResource {

    @Autowired
    MyComplexObjectDAO daoInstance;

    @Path("findObject/{id}")
    @GET
    public MyComplexObject findObject( @PathParam(value="id") String id ) {
        return daoInstance.findObject( id );
    }

    @Path("saveObject")
    @PUT
    public MyComplexObject saveObject( MyComplexObject objectToSave ) {
        MyComplexObject savedObject = daoInstance.saveObject( objectToSave );
        return savedObject;
    }

}
```

So you can see I'm autowiring a DAO object using spring, and then I use the DAO methods in the REST handlers.

The 'findObject' call seems to work fine - so far it works exactly as I expect it to.

The 'saveObject' call is not working the way I want and that's what I need some advice on.

You can see that I'm trying to directly take an instance of my complex object as a parameter to the REST method. Additionally I would like to return an instance of the complex object after it's been saved.

I put together some 'client' code for testing this out.

```
@Test
public void saveTest() {
    WebResource wsClient = createWebServiceClient();

    MyComplexObject unsavedInstance = createMyComplexObject();

    MyComplexObject savedInstance = 
            wsClient
            .path("saveObject")
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
            .put(MyComplexObject.class, unsavedInstance);

    assertNotNull(savedIntent);
}
```

Which is returning the following error:

```
com.sun.jersey.api.client.UniformInterfaceException: PUT http://localhost:8081/rest/myresource/save returned a response status of 400 Bad Request
```

I don't see why this isn't working and I think I've tried just about everything I can think of. Any help or direction would be very much appreciated.

Thanks so much!

Comment: I think I may have found my problem.
`MyComplexObject` was actually subclass of `MyBaseComplexObject` - I was using the 'joined class' inheritance model for my ORM layer. I had `MyBaseComplexObject` defined as an abstract class, ie: it could not be instantiated. Making this a real, non-abstract, concrete class all its own seems to be making a difference in my tests. I'll report back when I have more to say about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

switching to the 'concrete class' solution I alluded to in my earlier comment is what fixed things up for me.

Answer (score 1):

I see that you call the accept() method in your test client (which means that a "Accept:" header is added to the request, indicating the server what type of representation you would like). However, you don't call the type() method to add a "Content-type:" header and inform the server that you are sending XML data. See http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/client-api.html#d4e644 for examples.

Side remark: your URLs are not RESTful - you should avoid verbs in your path:

So, instead of:

```
/api/findObject/{id}
/api/saveObject
```

You should use:

```
/api/objects/{id}
/api/objects
```

Last note: to create an object on calling /api/objects, you should do a POST and not a PUT to adhere to REST best practices and widely adopted patterns.